# Centering a TD on mobile in Gmail email

Tags: html, email, gmail

Running into my regular struggles with email template designs, in particular that Gmail removes classes and thus I can't center a td via any means. Is there any way at all to change the "align" from left to center on the td with the image? Maybe I can comment in additional TDs on sides to center it, if Gmail permits it. I'm at a loss.

Template is mildly frankensteined from a template block editor.

```
<table class="row" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" width="280" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td align="left">
            <table style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
            <tbody><tr>
            <td align="left">
            <table style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; width:auto !important;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
            <tbody><tr>
            <td class="img-responsive" width="280" align="left">
            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;" border="0"><img alt="280x200x1" src="#" style="width:100%; height:auto;" width="280" height="200"></a>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>
            </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="center">
            <table data-primary-order="1" data-primary-type="bgcolor" data-bgcolor="Columns" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" align="center">
            <tbody><tr>
            <td align="center">
            <table style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; max-width:90%; width:90%;" width="90%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height:15px; font-size:0;" height="15">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table style="width:auto !important;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                <tbody><tr>
            <td data-color="Titles" data-size="Titles" data-min="14" data-max="46" style="color: #333333; font-family: 'roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 13px; line-height: 22.1px;" align="left">text text<br>text text</td></tr>
                </tbody></table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            <td style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height:15px; font-size:0;" height="15">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
            </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code should resolve your issue. When viewing the code you will see there is an element with an id of "I CHANGED FROM LEFT TO CENTER". This seemed to cause the issue, hopefully it works for you too!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table class="row" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" width="280" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td align="left">
            <table style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
            <tbody><tr>
            <td align="left">
            <table style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; width:auto !important;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
            <tbody><tr>
            <td class="img-responsive" width="280" align="left">
            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;" border="0"><img alt="280x200x1" src="#" style="width:100%; height:auto;" width="280" height="200"></a>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>
            </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="center">
            <table data-primary-order="1" data-primary-type="bgcolor" data-bgcolor="Columns" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" align="center">
            <tbody><tr>
            <td align="center">
            <table style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; max-width:90%; width:90%;" width="90%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height:15px; font-size:0;" height="15">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table style="width:auto !important;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" id="I CHANGED FROM LEFT TO CENTER">
                <tbody><tr>
            <td data-color="Titles" data-size="Titles" data-min="14" data-max="46" style="color: #333333; font-family: 'roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 13px; line-height: 22.1px;" style="text-align: right;">text text<br>text text</td></tr>
                </tbody></table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            <td style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height:15px; font-size:0;" height="15">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
            </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>

</body>
</html>
```